# How to get Last Logout time of user in Openfire Server using php code

Tags: php, xmpp, openfire

How to get Last Logout time of user in Openfire Server using php code.
How i will achieve this I am new on Openfire.

I googled a lot. But haven't found any article about my questions. Is there any way to get "last seen" or "last activity" date from Openfire server?

Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: same problem with me.

Comment: The [list of protocols supported by OpenFire](https://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/openfire/docs/latest/documentation/protocol-support.html) contains [XEP-0012: Last Activity](http://www.xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0012.html), so that would probably be a good place to start.

Comment: Can you please suggest me how can we integrate it using PHP.

Answer (score 2):

You can use XMPPHP library to manage XMPP connection to Openfire in PHP; there are several fork from the project originally hosted on Google Code, for example:

- https://github.com/BirknerAlex/XMPPHP
- https://github.com/cweiske/xmpphp

Example of usage are easy to find, however here are some of them:

- [XMPPHP to Openfire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26248960/xmpphp-to-openfire)
- [XMPPHP and Openfire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14112624/xmpphp-and-openfire)

In your case, after having created your connection to XMPP server (Openfire) with:

```
$conn = new XMPPHP_XMPP(...);
$conn->connect();
```

you can send a generic XML message with [`$conn->send($xml);`](https://github.com/cweiske/xmpphp/blob/master/XMPPHP/XMLStream.php#L766) or a specific IQ message with [`$conn->sendIq(...);`](https://github.com/cweiske/xmpphp/blob/master/XMPPHP/XMPP.php#L252).

Follow [xep-0012](http://www.xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0012.html) doc to create appropriate XML to obtain Last Activity info for a user.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to communicate on XMPP and you have access to Openfire's database, then you can also query the database for last seen time.

Table: ofPresence

You can query for "offlineDate" against "username" and you will get time in milliseconds: 001448886257729

Whenever a user comes online (sends his presence to Openfire Server), his entry is removed from this table. So for an online user, you won't get any record.

Hope it will help.

Comment: Yes you are right.I did the same thing.Thanks.Can you please let me know after how much time i can get the "offlineDate" from openfire.after user goes offline.

Comment: It's immediate (as soon as Server identifies that user is no more connected).